# How to prevent JavaFX to call method event? JavaFX

Tags: java, events, javafx

I have a simple question.

Let's say that this method is for a table view. When I click on row inside my table view, then this method calls.

```
@FXML
void rowClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    // Select a row here
}
```

But when this code select a row on my table view, then the method will be called again. How can I prevent JavaFX to just call-by-itself and only user have the rights to activate this method by just clicking the table view?

Comment: If you are using the proper event on the table, it should only be triggered by an actual click, not selecting an item via the `SelectionModel`.

    <TableView fx:id="tableView" onMouseClicked="#rowClicked">

Something else is probably going on. Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example. That will help you find the issue and us to understand what help you need.

Comment: @SephB I have this fxml code `<TableView fx:id=tableView onMouseClicked=#rowClicked>` Yes. I will post an example later.